# Highcharts displaying year in date time axis in a separate line

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I want to display year as following chart.

[image]

Please note that label only have one character.
So how can I display the year as above chart?

Comment: Have you tried to use [grouped categories](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories) plugin?

Comment: Hi, The X axis is a date time axis. Are we supporting "grouped categories" on date time axis?

Comment: No it's not. Just your screenshot looks like categories. Then how about using second xAxis `linkedTo` the first one? And setting `tickInterval` to one year?

Comment: Ahh that will be a thing that I can try. Could you point me to an example of multiple x-axis?

Comment: I just tried with example with two data series for two axis. I am not sure how to link two axes with one data series.

Comment: You can't, but as I said, you can link two axes together, using [`linkedTo`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.linkedTo) option.